# Python fails to parallelize buffer reads

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, gil

I'm having performances issues in multi-threading.

I have a code snippet that reads 8MB buffers in parallel:

```
import copy
import itertools
import threading
import time

# Basic implementation of thread pool.
# Based on multiprocessing.Pool
class ThreadPool:

   def __init__(self, nb_threads):
      self.nb_threads = nb_threads

   def map(self, fun, iter):

      if self.nb_threads <= 1:
         return map(fun, iter)
      nb_threads = min(self.nb_threads, len(iter))

      # ensure 'iter' does not evaluate lazily
      # (generator or xrange...)
      iter = list(iter)

      # map to results list
      results = [None] * nb_threads
      def wrapper(i):
         def f(args):
            results[i] = map(fun, args)
         return f

      # slice iter in chunks
      chunks = [iter[i::nb_threads] for i in range(nb_threads)]

      # create threads
      threads = [threading.Thread(target = wrapper(i), args = [chunk]) \
                 for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks)]

      # start and join threads
      [thread.start() for thread in threads]
      [thread.join() for thread in threads]

      # reorder results
      r = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(None, *results)))
      return r

payload = [0] * (1000 * 1000)  # 8 MB
payloads = [copy.deepcopy(payload) for _ in range(40)]

def process(i):
   for i in payloads[i]:
      j = i + 1

if __name__ == '__main__':

   for nb_threads in [1, 2, 4, 8, 20]:

      t = time.time()
      c = time.clock()

      pool = ThreadPool(nb_threads)
      pool.map(process, xrange(40))

      t = time.time() - t
      c = time.clock() - c

      print nb_threads, t, c
```

Output:

```
1 1.04805707932 1.05
2 1.45473504066 2.23
4 2.01357698441 3.98
8 1.56527090073 3.66
20 1.9085559845 4.15
```

Why does the *threading* module miserably fail at parallelizing mere buffer reads?
Is it because of the GIL? Or because of some weird configuration on my machine, one process
is allowed only one access to the RAM at a time (I have decent speed-up if I switch *ThreadPool* for *multiprocessing.Pool* is the code above)?

I'm using CPython 2.7.8 on a linux distro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Python's GIL prevents Python code from running in parallel across multiple threads. You describe your code as doing "buffer reads", but it's really running arbitrary Python code (in this case, iterating over a list adding 1 to other integers). If your threads were making blocking system calls (like reading from a file, or from a network socket), then the GIL would usually be released while the thread blocked waiting on the external data. But since most operations on Python objects can have side effects, you can't do several of them in parallel.

One important reason for this is that CPython's garbage collector uses reference counting as its main way to know when an object can be cleaned up. If several threads try to update the reference count of the same object at the same time, they might end up in a race condition and leave the object with the wrong count. The GIL prevents that from happening, as only one thread can be making such internal changes at a time. Every time your `process` code does `j = i + 1`, it's going to be updating the reference counts of the integer objects `0` and `1` a couple of times each. That's exactly the kind of thing the GIL exists to guard.

Comment: Thanks Blckknght. I don't get the part about updating references though. I'm incrementing different instances of "j", each of them having a different reference counter. The object "1" is a kinda constant, you mean there in only one reference of it, shared among the threads? (which in that case, I'd agree with you on the race hazard on the reference counter). What do mean when you refer to integer object 0 ?